# Translating "layout strings" in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, internationalization, translation

I'm developing a site in Drupal 6 that will be translated to over 10 idioms. For the main content, I'm using CCK + i18n. But there are some text in the site's layout that I'm not sure how to translate.

For example, let's suppose that it's a site that sells software. In the page that lists all available software (which are Drupal nodes), I have some text in the sidebar that says "*Check out the best selling programs!*". From what I know, this text could be:

1. In a block (good)
2. Directly in the template for this page (bad)

Both of these options would use the [t() function](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t) to translate the text. The problem is that t() uses the string as the key to create the association between the original string and its translations. If, for example, I translate the text to 10 different languages and tomorrow I decide to make a small change to the english text, I'll need to create all the translations again.

A third option would be to have a custom Content Type for this type of string, and in this case the translation would be made creating a translated version of the node (i18n). However, this seems too much work and not the right way to accomplish it.

Does Drupal or some community module provides a better way to translated these strings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the latest version of the i18n module should support translating block content and titles. See also http://drupal-translation.com/content/translating-block-contents.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have a block for each language (the site is huge). And the second method described in that link uses t().